# Create Javascript Object with methods and class from deffered JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to create an object with global scope which has data loaded from an external JSON file. 
I want to use the data in this object once the document has loaded. i.e not wait for user input. I am trying to use the jquery differed method. I assume that the Jquery get method generates the appropriate differed object for me to use later. 
The code for declaring the object is below

```
var myData = {
init: function () {
    $.getJSON('data/data.json', function (raw) {    
        myData.data = raw; 
        alert(myData.data['UWLO']['name']);
        yes = true;
        $.each(raw, function (code, details) {
            if (yes){
                alert(code);
            }
            yes = false;
            nameList[details.name] = code;
        });
        //alert(nameList);
    });
},
data: {},
nameList: {},
findByCode: function (code) {
    return myData.data[code];
},
getCode: function (name) {
    return nameList[name];
},
getNameStrings: function () {
    return Object.keys(nameList);
}
}
```

The code as it appears to initialise the object is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.when(myData.init()).then(function () {
        alert(myData.nameList);
    });
});
```

The alert(myData.data['UWLO']['name']); request gives the correct value so the json file is loaded correctly and of the correct format
the alert(code); line works so the script correctly enters the loop
I think the problem lies with generating nameList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. `$.ajax` functions return a `deferred` object's promise. So you have to return that from your `init` function to be able to use it later. Try this:

```
init: function () {
    return $.getJSON('data/data.json', function (raw) {
```

You can also simplify the other snippet:

```
myData.init().done(function() {
    //...
});
```

Edit - Actually, in order to be explicit about the order the callbacks occur (in case this is more complex in your actual solution), creating your own deferred object like this might be better:

```
init: function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.getJSON('data/data.json', function (raw) {    
        myData.data = raw; 
        alert(myData.data['UWLO']['name']);
        yes = true;
        $.each(raw, function (code, details) {
            if (yes){
                alert(code);
            }
            yes = false;
            nameList[details.name] = code;                
        });
        //alert(nameList);
        def.resolve();
    });
    return def.promise();
},
```

Comment: Just to clarify $.getJSON() is asyncrous so the return def.promise(); will execute first and the variable def will be resolved when def.resolve() is called. why to you pass def.promise() out of the function rather than the variable def

Comment: The promise is missing some functions, like `resolve`. It's a way of making sure that external functions can't resolve your deferred before you intend for it to be done. See [`deferred.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

Comment: Thanks this is helping to explain differed jquery but it is still not working. is nameList correct created as a dictionary for use in the init function

Comment: You're referencing `myData.data`, but only `nameList`. Those should probably be the same. Try `myData.nameList`.